# Should I use nvidia graphic card to watch movie?

Tags: vlc

I'm always watching movie with VLC media player, but I'm afraid that it will hurt the laptop motherboard intel graphic. Should I use build in graphic card to open VLC media player to reduce the laptop burden?

For example, optirun VLC on terminal instead.

Answer (score 0):

If it has hardware decoding, try using it. I do not personally have that card, so I can't give you specifics. I would check if there are any "additional drivers". It is unlikely that watching too many movies will hurt your laptop, but if it has you worried find an application that can display your cpu temp. If the fans are all cranked up and you crash when while doing something cpu intensive, that would be a sign it is over heating.

My desktop gtx660 runs saucy and tahr excellent. It has opengl and lots of supported hardware decoding. So yes, use a recent nvidia card if you can.

Comment: I have a application called tlp and it tracks my laptop temp around 42 with battery mode and 52 with charges mode, but when I use optirun...my laptop temp raised